# Should I normalize the data (capital stock series) after deflating it with whole price index?

Tags: normalization

I am working on across industries. I want to know that after deflation capital stock of large scale industries with whole sale price index, Is there need of normalizing the data series?

Comment: What is the analytical context of your question?  "Working ... across industries" is not specific enough information to enable people to provide objectively correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know how your data looks, but I can give a general hint, when to use normalization.

In general you normalize your data, if you have **different features** and the **mean and standard** or those features **differ significantly**. If you want to weight your different features by their individual weights, you do not need to normalize them. But if you want each feature to have the same impact on your result, you have to normalize your data.

The following example is slightly different from one given in the following [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461471370):

> An Introduction to Statistical Learning by Gareth James, Daniela Witten and Trevor Hastie Robert Tibshirani

You have an online store wants to analyze the shopping behavior of their customers to group them in different groups be their shopping behavior. They sell socks and computers. If now a customer buys 16 pairs of socks and only 1 Computer, the socks be weighted to high without normalization, because computers are bought in general more rarely than socks and in addition computers are much more expensive. So it would not be in interest of the store to not scale their data.

[image: Number of articles bought by different shoppers]

**Number of articles bought by different shoppers**

[image: Costs for the articles]

**Costs for the articles**

I hope this information gives you some idea if you should normalize your data or not.